# Why Hamburger menu does not toggle when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

My hamburger menu displays perfectly on small screens but does not activate when I click it. I implemented the JavaScript code which should toggle the menu when clicked, but it doesn't work at all. I made the hamburger with CSS using the `span` tag. When clicked, the hamburger menu should toggle into an X, but it does not toggle. Is something wrong with my script?

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
    navMenu.classList.toggle("active");

})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.2%;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

body {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.header {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 52px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header .navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.nav-heading {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    color: #ff6a00;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    gap: 4rem;



}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;



}

.nav-menu a {

    transition: 0.7s ease;
    margin-right: 4rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 72, 136);
}


.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.bar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #f7f7f7f7;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
    .hamburger {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 3rem;
    }

    .navbar .nav-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .hamburger .active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .hamburger .active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);

    }

    .hamburger .active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);

    }

    .nav-menu {
        position: fixed;
        left: -100%;
        top: 70px;
        gap: 0;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #000000;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: 0.3s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .nav-menu a {
        margin: 16px 0;
    }

    /*this is for when you active the the hamburger*/

    .nav-menu .active {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HamBurger Nav</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ResponNavbar.css">
    <script src="ResponNvar.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a class="nav-heading" href="#">Ocean-fontier</a>
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="hamburger">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>

        </nav>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Only one change was needed - change all your CSS rules which have (eg) `.nav-menu .active` to `.nav-menu.active` (with no space). The latter is how you target an element with both classes, whereas with the space it's a parent-child relationship - effective all elements of class `active` which are *inside* one of class `nav-menu`. Of course the former is what you actually want here.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
    navMenu.classList.toggle("active");

})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.2%;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

body {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.header {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 52px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header .navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.nav-heading {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    color: #ff6a00;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    gap: 4rem;



}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;



}

.nav-menu a {

    transition: 0.7s ease;
    margin-right: 4rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 72, 136);
}


.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.bar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #f7f7f7f7;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
    .hamburger {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 3rem;
    }

    .navbar .nav-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);

    }

    .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);

    }

    .nav-menu {
        position: fixed;
        left: -100%;
        top: 70px;
        gap: 0;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #000000;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: 0.3s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .nav-menu a {
        margin: 16px 0;
    }

    /*this is for when you active the the hamburger*/

    .nav-menu.active {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HamBurger Nav</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ResponNavbar.css">
    <script src="ResponNvar.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a class="nav-heading" href="#">Ocean-fontier</a>
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="hamburger">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>

        </nav>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ok but it isnt wroking in the broweser at all though

Comment: ok but i did all that but it click its isnt  showing when at smaller screens

Comment: well the above shows it working with the code you put here, and the small (but critical) adjustment I mentioned. If your actual code is significantly different you will need to post that here. (Ideally by editing your question.)